# brunch/jade single page client-only app

Tags: html, client, pug, brunch

Does anyone have an idea how to develop an local (client only!) application with brunch/jade? What I want: I don't need a server, I want to create an "application", meaning a simple "web page" that is run completely offline on an usb stick. Ideally it would consist of **one html**, **one css** and **one js file**.

Can this be done with brunch and jade?
I didn't really get the jade/brunch connection - I have my app now using static html pages made from jade templates. But what I would like more is to "concatenate" all html into one file which loads the content dynamically by javascript. The content is completely static, no need for a database.

I know how brunch works (already have a project with it). What I don't know is: How do I manage the links and the routing within the single page site without a server side part? Do I need a Js library for that?

Any hints welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You'll probably compile 2 scripts, `app.js` and `templates.js`.

You'll need to write or include client-side router; [jkingyens/brunch-dutch-baby](https://github.com/jkingyens/brunch-dutch-baby) uses Jade + [Backbone.Router](https://github.com/jkingyens/brunch-dutch-baby/blob/master/app/router.coffee).

Comment: Thanks (after all the time). I did it manually, used backbone.js just for the router and the models. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

There are many skeltons here: http://brunch.io/skeletons.html. We can choose many types of skelton.

So you want to use brunch with jade.
It seems https://github.com/TessaHarmon/brunch-jade-stylus is minimum.

```
$ brunch new gh:TessaHarmon/brunch-jade-stylus new-application
$ cd new-application
$ brunch watch --server
24 Feb 10:14:05 - info: application started on http://localhost:3333/
24 Feb 10:14:05 - info: compiled 4 files into 2 files, copied index.html in 357ms

/Users/banyan/tmp/new-application/node_modules/static-jade-brunch/node_modules/jade/lib/runtime.js:231
  throw err;
        ^
Error: app/index.static.jade:1
  > 1| !!! 5
    2| // if IE 6
    3|   <html id="ie6" lang="en">
    4| // if IE 7
```

Woops, jade complains. Just fixing `!!! 5` to `document html` in `app/index.static.jade`. Then again `brunch watch --server`, now we can see blank page of `Brunch-jade-stylus` at http://localhost:3333. If you want to change sass instead of stylus, you need to use `sass-brunch` in `package.json`.

Comment: Hm. This is not what I asked for - maybe I wrote my question not very understandable. I know skeletons,, I already have a project with jade (stylus/sass don't bother me). What I want to know is HOW exactly I get the application to compile into one file, what has to be loaded in the html file? I don't really get the jade system and the jade page says nothing about it (that I understand). How are the jade contents invoked? Do I need a backend like backbone.js, etc.? How can I provide e.g. 2 links, and when I click on each link the corresponding jade page is shown. That's what I need.

Comment: `brunch build`, then see under public dir. everything is combined into 1 file. If you don't need pushState, plain a tag will work.

Comment: ;-) I know how brunch works... My problem is: if there is a tag <a href="page2.html">Page2</a>, the link works because there IS A `page2.html` file. if everything is compiled into one file, where does the `a href` link point to? Which Js command needs to be invoked to load another jade page here? It's not enough that there is only one file - AFAIK I need something like a backend - not right? Could you give an example solution for the `a href` problem? I think my question is a bit more abstract than you think ;-)

Comment: sorry, now i got to know what you want (I'm not good at English :P) Yes, you are definitely correct. we don't need server. I have bunch of application it runs on Amazon S3 with html/js/css. normally we use pushState if browser accept or just hash. There are many library to solve this matter. maybe you can have a look at http://backbonejs.org/#Router.
This site itself consists one html (http://backbonejs.org/index.html) and link is like this http://i.gyazo.com/ee70e3293fcad80f657485b457deb9cb.png, hope this helps :)

Comment: AAAHHH, that enlightens me! Thank you very much. Could you post that as (maybe new) answer, so I can mark it as correct one (and you get the hard earned credits)? ;-)

Comment: Could you post that last comment as new answer, so I will mark it as correct one!